# Struggling to make my Break Session work in my Pomodoro Clock

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popper.js

I am doing a Pomodoro Clock project and am having trouble with my Break Session not working after my timer has reached zero. The Break Session Increment and Decrement buttons work fine, it's just getting it to do what it's intended to do.

Ignore the code commented out, it was alternative work I had tried before and ultimately decided to go with what I have now.:):)

```js
var breakPlease = document.getElementById("breakPlease").innerHTML = 5;
/*
function increaseBreak() {

let breakLength = document.getElementById("break-length");
if (parseFloat(breakLength.innerText) < 60 ) {
breakLength.innerText = parseFloat(breakLength.innerText) + 1
  }
}

function decreaseBreak() {

let breakLength = document.getElementById("break-length");
if (parseFloat(breakLength.innerText) > 0) {
breakLength.innerText = parseFloat(breakLength.innerText) - 1
  }
}
*/

/*
function increaseSession() {
  
let sessionLength = document.getElementById("session-length");
if (parseFloat(sessionLength.innerText) < 60) {
let increasedSession = parseFloat(sessionLength.innerText) + 1
sessionLength.innerText = increasedSession;
document.getElementById("startingMinutes").innerText = increasedSession;
  }
}


function decreaseSession() {
  
let sessionLength = document.getElementById("session-length");
if (parseFloat(sessionLength.innerText) > 0) {
let decreasedSession = parseFloat(sessionLength.innerText) - 1
sessionLength.innerText = decreasedSession; 
document.getElementById("startingMinutes").innerText = decreasedSession;
  }  
}
*/
let startingMinutes = 25;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;


function increaseBreak() {
  if (breakPlease < 60) {
  document.getElementById('breakPlease').innerHTML = ++breakPlease;
  }
}

function decreaseBreak() {
  if (breakPlease >= 2) {
  document.getElementById('breakPlease').innerHTML = --breakPlease;
  }
}


function increaseSession() {
  if (startingMinutes < 60) {
  document.getElementById('timeItself').innerHTML = ++startingMinutes;
  time = startingMinutes * 60;
  }
}

function decreaseSession() { 
   if (startingMinutes >= 2) {
   document.getElementById('timeItself').innerHTML = --startingMinutes;
   time = startingMinutes * 60;
  }
}


const countdownEl = document.getElementById('countdown');

let interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

function updateCountdown() {
  const minutesLeft = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let secondsLeft = time % 60;
  
  if (minutesLeft === 0 && secondsLeft === 0) clearInterval(interval);
  
  secondsLeft = secondsLeft < 10 ? '0' + secondsLeft : secondsLeft;
  
  countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutesLeft}: ${secondsLeft}`;
  time--;
  
}


function startAndStop() {
  if (interval === null) {
    interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }
  console.log('sAS clicked')
}



function resetTime() {
  console.log('rT clicked')
  startingMinutes = 25;
  time = startingMinutes * 60;
  if (interval == null) {
    updateCountdown();
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: verdaan;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><center>makingWater</center></p>
    <h1><center>25 + 5 'clock'</center></h1>
    
    <br></br><br></br>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col">
          <div id="break-label">
            <p>Break Length</p>
          </div>
          <div id="break-length">
            <h4><span id="breakPlease">5</span></h4>
          </div>
          <button id="break-increment" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="increaseBreak()">
            Break Increase
          </button>
          <button id="break-decrement" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="decreaseBreak()">
           Break Decrease
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col ">
          <div id="session-label">
            <p>Session Length</p>
            <div id="session-length">
              <h4><span id="timeItself">25</span></h4>
            </div>
            <button id="session-increment" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="increaseSession()">
              Session Increase
            </button>
            <button id="session-decrement" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="decreaseSession()">
              Session Decrease
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col">
            <div id="timer-label">
              <br></br><br></br>
              <p>Session</p>
            </div>
        <p>
        <div id="time-left">
          <h2 id="countdown" id="time"><span id="minutes">25</span>:<span id="seconds"> 00</span></h2>
          </p>
        <audio id="beep">
            <source src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/pang/arrow.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    <source src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/pang/arrow.mp3" type="audio/wav" />
      <source src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/pang/arrow.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
          <button id="start_stop" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="startAndStop()">Start/Stop</button>
          <button id="reset" class="btn" onclick="resetTime()">Reset</button>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to control your session type. If it is a break, update the time with the break time, otherwise with the work time

```js
var breakPlease = document.getElementById("breakPlease").innerHTML = 5;

let startingMinutes = 25;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;
let isBreak = false;

function increaseBreak() {
  if (breakPlease < 60) {
  document.getElementById('breakPlease').innerHTML = ++breakPlease;
  }
}

function decreaseBreak() {
  if (breakPlease >= 2) {
  document.getElementById('breakPlease').innerHTML = --breakPlease;
  }
}


function increaseSession() {
  if (startingMinutes < 60) {
  document.getElementById('timeItself').innerHTML = ++startingMinutes;
  time = startingMinutes * 60;
  }
}

function decreaseSession() { 
   if (startingMinutes >= 2) {
   document.getElementById('timeItself').innerHTML = --startingMinutes;
   time = startingMinutes * 60;
  }
}

const countdownEl = document.getElementById('countdown');

let interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

function updateCountdown() {
  const minutesLeft = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let secondsLeft = time % 60;
  
  if (minutesLeft === 0 && secondsLeft === 0) {
      isBreak = !isBreak;
      time = (isBreak ? breakPlease : startingMinutes) * 60;
      console.log(isBreak ? 'break' : 'work', 'start with', time);
  }
  
  secondsLeft = secondsLeft < 10 ? '0' + secondsLeft : secondsLeft;
  
  countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutesLeft}: ${secondsLeft}`;
  time--;
 
}

function startAndStop() {
  if (interval === null) {
    interval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }
  console.log('sAS clicked')
}

function resetTime() {
  console.log('rT clicked')
  startingMinutes = 25;
  time = startingMinutes * 60;
  if (interval == null) {
    updateCountdown();
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: verdaan;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><center>makingWater</center></p>
    <h1><center>25 + 5 'clock'</center></h1>
    
    <br></br><br></br>
    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col">
          <div id="break-label">
            <p>Break Length</p>
          </div>
          <div id="break-length">
            <h4><span id="breakPlease">5</span></h4>
          </div>
          <button id="break-increment" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="increaseBreak()">
            Break Increase
          </button>
          <button id="break-decrement" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="decreaseBreak()">
           Break Decrease
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col ">
          <div id="session-label">
            <p>Session Length</p>
            <div id="session-length">
              <h4><span id="timeItself">25</span></h4>
            </div>
            <button id="session-increment" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="increaseSession()">
              Session Increase
            </button>
            <button id="session-decrement" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="decreaseSession()">
              Session Decrease
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col">
            <div id="timer-label">
              <br></br><br></br>
              <p>Session</p>
            </div>
        <p>
        <div id="time-left">
          <h2 id="countdown" id="time"><span id="minutes">25</span>:<span id="seconds"> 00</span></h2>
          </p>
        <audio id="beep">
            <source src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/pang/arrow.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
    <source src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/pang/arrow.mp3" type="audio/wav" />
      <source src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/pang/arrow.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
          <button id="start_stop" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="startAndStop()">Start/Stop</button>
          <button id="reset" class="btn" onclick="resetTime()">Reset</button>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: wow thankyou so much, you have no idea how much that helps me :D

Comment: @makingWater then you can mark my answer as a solution :)